# Playing microsoft smooth streaming file from a local machine

Tags: url

I want to play a smooth streaming (.ims) file with smooth streaming sample player on my local machine on which i don't have server.

I read that you should give a url of the file in the `InitParams` param section in the html of the player. I tried with URL like `file://localhost/D:/SmoothStreamin/A_MSS_1280_720p_24fps_200kbps/A_MSS_1280_720p_24fps_200kbps.ism` but it didnt worked.

Comment: Ok, I'll just grab my crystal ball and divine the solution. Maybe I should stock up on tea leaves, too, while I'm at it. In the meantime, maybe you could provide some code so the non-psychics out there can help solve your problem too.

Answer (score 0):

file://localhost/D:/SmoothStreamin/A_MSS_1280_720p_24fps_200kbps/A_MSS_1280_720p_24fps_200kbps.ism **/Manifest**

dont forget the manifest part.